# Windows Kerberos Pre-Auth Failed (4771)

Tags: windows, siem

Is there an easy way to distinguish 4771 events from a real attack perspective vs. someone having a stale session with an old password?

If you don't get logs from all endpoints and rely on Domain Controllers, you have to key off of 4771 and 4625 for failures, where 4771 is the Kerberos events from the domain joined computers to the DCs.

It's nice having visibility across the endpoints without getting logs from everything but for these 4771 events, most of the alerts I see are just stale sessions and non-security events. I don't see any sub code or item to key off of for stale/old password vs. real attack.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time these events are noisy in a large user environment with a password change policy. Most of the time this happens when an account's password is expired and it is tied with some application/service/task which keeps trying login again and again.

If you have SIEM or log management solution, you can create a rule to ignore 4771 events for account's password was recently reset 4723/4724 (say in the last 24hrs).

Comment: But if there is no set timeout on the servers, then ignoring 4771 events from X user one a 4723/4724 event is tripped wouldn't help. It would just delay the alerts for 24 hours. Which I understand, there should be a forced disconnect but just playing devil's advocate.

Comment: ah then look for 0x18 code in the event 4771. 0x18 indicates a bad password. If you more 0x18 in a short time, it could be an attack. Some more events to monitor are explained in this article https://www.trimarcsecurity.com/single-post/2018/05/06/Trimarc-Research-Detecting-Password-Spraying-with-Security-Event-Auditing

Comment: Looking for 0x18 doesn't help me at all. 0x18 means bad password which could be a legitimate attack or someone just changed their password which makes their stale sessions now a "bad password".

Answer (score 0):

I ended up giving up on 4771 and 4625 events. Instead I'm just focusing on the account lockout event ID and then doing correlation rules based on X lockouts in Y hours to determine brute force.

This has been a lot cleaner since not all of the 4771's truly lockout accounts and it's cut back on false positives drastically.